# Issue building C++ example provided by uWebsockets using CMake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, uwebsockets, fetchcontent

I have the following directory structure for my project that utilizes [uWebsockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) and I am trying to run the example provided by [in uWebsockets examples folder](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/examples/EchoServer.cpp). Interestingly, `uWebsockets` does not have any `CMakeLists.txt` in its root folder as to how to build the examples.

I am able to configure and generate successfully with CMake in Windows. However, I have issues building  target `uwebsocketsExample1`.

I'd like to be able to use `FetchContent` and bring in `uWebsockets` and its submodules `uSockets`, etc., by `external\uWebsockets\CMakeLists.txt`. Could someone help me build [EchoServer.cpp](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/examples/EchoServer.cpp)?

```
my-app
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
├───examples
│       CMakeLists.txt
│       uwebsockets.example.cpp
│
└───external
    └───uwebsockets
            CMakeLists.txt
```

**Contents of `my-app\CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(my-app VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

add_subdirectory(external/uWebsockets)
add_subdirectory(examples)
```

**Contents of `external\uwebsockets\CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(libuWebsockets VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

FetchContent_Declare(uwebsockets
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.git)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(uwebsockets)

add_library(uwebsockets INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(uwebsockets INTERFACE ${uwebsockets_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
add_library(uwebsockets::uwebsockets ALIAS uwebsockets)
```

**Contents of `examples\CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(projExamples VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(uwebsocketsExample1 uwebsockets.example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(uwebsocketsExample1 PRIVATE uwebsockets::uwebsockets)
```

**Contents of `examples\uwebsockets.example.cpp`**:

```
/* We simply call the root header file "App.h", giving you uWS::App and uWS::SSLApp */
#include "App.h"

/* This is a simple WebSocket echo server example.
 * You may compile it with "WITH_OPENSSL=1 make" or with "make" */

int main() {
    /* ws->getUserData returns one of these */
    struct PerSocketData {
        /* Fill with user data */
    };

    /* Keep in mind that uWS::SSLApp({options}) is the same as uWS::App() when compiled without SSL support.
     * You may swap to using uWS:App() if you don't need SSL */
    uWS::App({
                     /* There are example certificates in uWebSockets.js repo */
                     .key_file_name = "misc/key.pem",
                     .cert_file_name = "misc/cert.pem",
                     .passphrase = "1234"
             }).ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
            /* Settings */
            .compression = uWS::CompressOptions(uWS::DEDICATED_COMPRESSOR_4KB | uWS::DEDICATED_DECOMPRESSOR),
            .maxPayloadLength = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
            .idleTimeout = 16,
            .maxBackpressure = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
            .closeOnBackpressureLimit = false,
            .resetIdleTimeoutOnSend = false,
            .sendPingsAutomatically = true,
            /* Handlers */
            .upgrade = nullptr,
            .open = [](auto */*ws*/) {
                /* Open event here, you may access ws->getUserData() which points to a PerSocketData struct */

            },
            .message = [](auto *ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
                /* This is the opposite of what you probably want; compress if message is LARGER than 16 kb
                 * the reason we do the opposite here; compress if SMALLER than 16 kb is to allow for
                 * benchmarking of large message sending without compression */
                ws->send(message, opCode, message.length() < 16 * 1024);
            },
            .drain = [](auto */*ws*/) {
                /* Check ws->getBufferedAmount() here */
            },
            .ping = [](auto */*ws*/, std::string_view) {
                /* Not implemented yet */
            },
            .pong = [](auto */*ws*/, std::string_view) {
                /* Not implemented yet */
            },
            .close = [](auto */*ws*/, int /*code*/, std::string_view /*message*/) {
                /* You may access ws->getUserData() here */
            }
    }).listen(9001, [](auto *listen_socket) {
        if (listen_socket) {
            std::cout << "Listening on port " << 9001 << std::endl;
        }
    }).run();
}
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: When I build,  I get `Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory`.

Comment: And do you *have* that file somewhere on your computer?

Comment: I don't have the file. I am trying to create a self-sufficient CMakeLists.txt that `FetchContent`s all the dependencies.

Comment: "Could someone help me ..." is NOT a question, suitable for Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. "I am trying to create a self-sufficient CMakeLists.txt that FetchContents all the dependencies."  - So just follow that way. If your project needs zlib, then try FetchContent it. What is a **problem** with such direct approach? Note, that you may build `uWebsockets` without zlib, by adding `-DUWS_NO_ZLIB` to the compiler flags: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/build.c#L27.

Comment: If you go down that route, you will have to fetch and compile every dependency yourself. I would strongly advise against doing such "self-sufficient" build systems, as that is just reinventing the wheel. Instead, integrate with vcpkg or conan and have *them* build and install your dependencies for you. The build system for *your* application is then simply a file that states "I need uwebsockets" and your one .cpp file.